# Optimum method of connecting three different monitors to PC

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have three different monitors, two of which are DVI with the other being VGA. I can't seem to work out a way of hooking up each monitor to my graphics card. Currently I am using Lucid to run the VGA monitor on the internal graphics card, however this works terribly with Photoshop as it constantly crashes. My graphics card (Radeon 6950 Direct CUII) has to DVI ports and 4 display ports.

```
+-----------+  +-----------+  +----------+
| DVI       |  | DVI       |  | VGA      |
|-----------|  |-----------|  |----------|
|           |  |           |  |          |
|           |  |           |  |          |
|           |  |           |  |          |
+-----------+  +-----------+  +----------+

???????????????????????????????????????????

+- Radeon 6950 Direct CUII ---------------+
| DVI     DVI     DP     DP     DP     DP |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I have tried to solve this myself with a cheap VGA > DVI adapter (purchased before I got my DVI screen) and a cheap DVI > Display Port adaptor (I assume this is passive).

What is the best way to hook all three monitors up to the single graphics card. I know I will have to purchase another converter I just don't know which.